# Copy Date Value and Paste as actual Date not number

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a Google sheet with a cell (D1) that contains a formula (`=TODAY()`) to show the current date.  I am trying to create a macro that will simply copy the value of D1 as displayed (e.g., "5/18/2018") instead of the formula and then display that value as an actual date (i.e., "5/18/2018").  When I use Google sheets `PASTE SPECIAL (Paste Value Only)` it actually displays the number "43238" instead of "5/18/2018".  How do make it paste the actual date instead of the number?

Comment: Dates are stored as numbers. You need to format the cell to use the date format.

Answer (score 5):

You would use the text function.

If you have `=today()` in A1, you would use `=text(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy")`. (There are multiple formats for 'mm/dd/yyyy' if that's not the format you want.)

Alternatively you can pre-format the cell as a date, so pasting the value would automatically be displayed as a date.

Answer (score -1):

Before use `PASTE SPECIAL (Paste Value Only)`, try to use `PASTE SPECIAL (Paste Format Only)` **CTRL+Alt+V**, the **after** use `PASTE SPECIAL (Paste Value Only)` **CTRL+Shift+V**.

Worked fine here!